# apache solr - get daywise counts from date containing timezone

Tags: solr, lucene

How to extract date part from date containing timezone in solr and query to get counts wrt date.

```
row1 - <date name="call_start_time">2015-06-28T14:23:17Z</date>
row2 - <date name="call_start_time">2015-06-28T14:23:18Z</date>
row3 - <date name="call_start_time">2015-06-27T14:23:18Z</date>
```

want output as:
    call_start_time | count
    2015-06-27 | 1
    2015-06-28 | 2

Comment: Don't ask how to. Post your tried code. We don't have any code generation sevice.

Comment: @SamFarajpourGhamari, I need some pointers on how to get counts by extracting only date part from date containing timezone. eg, In postgres how we have fieldname::date BETWEEN '2015-07-05' AND '2015-07-21'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date Faceting Parameters is the solution for it.
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Date_Faceting:_per_day_for_the_past_5_days